# MockMvc test: model() and hasItem() methods are undefined

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I want to test my controller and use following to test it:

```
package spittr.web;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView;

import spittr.data.Spittle;
import spittr.data.SpittleRepository;

public class SpittleControllerTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldShowRecentSpittles() throws Exception {
        List<Spittle> expectedSpittles = createSpittleList(20);
        SpittleRepository mockRepository = Mockito.mock(SpittleRepository.class);

        Mockito.when(mockRepository.findSpittles(Long.MAX_VALUE, 20))
            .thenReturn(expectedSpittles);

        SpittleController controller = new SpittleController(mockRepository);

        MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
            .setSingleView(
                new InternalResourceView("/WEB-INF/views/spittles.jsp"))
            .build();

        mockMvc.perform(get("/spittles"))
            .andExpect(view().name("spittles"))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("spittleList"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("spittleList", hasItems(expectedSpittles.toArray())));
    }

    private List<Spittle> createSpittleList(int count) {
        List<Spittle> spittles = new ArrayList<Spittle>();

        for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
            spittles.add(new Spittle("Spittle " + i, new Date()));
        }

        return spittles;
    }
}
```

but the compiler cannot understand the **model()** method and **hasItem()** method in the assert section, which package or which .jar file should I import to this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`model()` is a static method on `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers`

`view()` is also a static method on `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers`

And `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers` is provided by `org.springframework:spring-test`.

I suspect you have this on your classpath otherwise none of the references to `MockMvc` would compile.

I think the issue you are encountering is with `hasItems()`, this comes from `org.hamcrest.Matchers`. The Maven coordinates for this dependency are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```